# How to make data reading and preprocessing faster in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have an algorithm for preprocessing data. It works with an *.arff format. [arff filles](http://repository.seasr.org/Datasets/UCI/arff/). I have a class attribute where I have the structure of the arff files. In a string I record the name of the attribute, values ​​it can take and their occurrence. In a numerical value, I record minimum maximum average and standard deviation. For the small files it works very well, but for large files it is very very slow. The file can have more than 10 GB.

I've tried many options - MemoryMapped Filles, BufferedStream. I think the problem is in the long preprocesing, but I don't know how make it faster.
I tried threads, but I don't know how.

```
private void readDataArff()
{
   string line = "";
   using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName))
   {
      string[] data;
      while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
      {
         if ((line.Contains('%')) || (line.Contains('@')) || (line.Contains("") && (!line.Contains(','))))
         continue; //skip header

         data = line.Split(',');

         for (int j = 0; j < attrList.Count; j++)// 
         {
            attrList[j].FilePath = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            attrList[j].Index = j;
            if (attrList[j].Type1 == "STRING")
            {
               foreach (var item in attrList[j].Values)
               {
                  if (item.Name == data[j])
                  {
                     item.Count += 1;
                     break;
                  }
               }
            }
            else if ((attrList[j].Type1 == "REAL" && (line != "") && (!line.Contains('@'))) ||
              (attrList[j].Type1 == "REAL" && (line != "") && (!line.Contains('@'))))
            {
               if ((data[j] == "?") || (data[j] == "") || (data[j] == " "))
               continue;
               attrList[j].Count += 1;
               attrList[j].Sum = double.Parse(data[j]) + attrList[j].Sum;
               double tmp = double.Parse(data[j]);
               if (attrList[j].Max < tmp)
                  attrList[j].Max = tmp;
               if (attrList[j].Min > tmp)
                  attrList[j].Min = tmp;
             }
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Processing 10GB of data will usually be pretty slow.  How long does it take?

Comment: I try only 800 megabytes.It takes 5 minutes.

Comment: That does not strike me as extraordinarily slow, given disk I/O and whatnot.  I'm not sure that optimizing your code will yield appreciably significant results.

Comment: First you could optimize your code... For example to allocate a var for attrList[j] instead of looking up the index every time. Also your elseif is like 1 || 1. Instead of multiple Contains you could use IndexOfAny.

Comment: First of all time how long it takes without any processing work, just to read the file so you know the base time. Also I note that you're doing the "header skip" check for every line, even when you have skipped the header. Couldn't you do that in a separate loop before the main processing loop? Also `line.Contains("")` will always be true, so remove it.

Comment: Try using a profiler to see where the time is spent.

Comment: Try reading the file without doing any processing. If that takes the same time then you know that the limiting factor is the speed of your hard disk, and optimizing the code won't do anything.

Comment: Reiterating what @DasKrümelmonster said, use a profiler. Beginning any sort of optimization without knowing where specifically the bottlenecks are is futile and will most likely make matters worse.

Comment: I use BufferedStream also StreamBuffer without processing.. the faster was (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"D:\bigfile.arff", u, false, 2056). It read 10GB in 3:49. I run profiler with Instrumentation method. It generate 3.5GB report..but I don't know what with it.

Comment: If you upload a compilable project and provide a download location for bigger (100MB) files, someone might do it four you. Otherwise you need to learn how to interpret the profiler report. For the integrated one see this blog entry: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/profiler/archive/2010/01/19/vs2010-investigating-a-sample-profiling-report-function-details.aspx

Comment: here is metadata  https://mega.co.nz/#!3RgkFb4Z!FyXZATXRsIWvDtQHMfywL2sUMS1sHmE_gBB3GgblkwM
and here is solution https://mega.co.nz/#!aUpwDBbC!GqM4hg0Lw2PJfceMwDAMPWdBcplMyCQqjmaSGYyf_9U
 the reading is in frmMain.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can try class BufferedStream, it is buffered implementation of the IStream.
2. You can optimise some of your code. preevalute some values, i.e. `double.Parse(data[j])`
3. Also you can write manual method string.Contains(char[] chrToSeek) that will scan string just once.

Comment: You're just guessing.  `BufferedStream` won't work... it's a red herring; `StreamReader` already contains a satisfactory buffer.  As for your other two suggestions, I would run a profiler on the code first.